# Framework dependency: could not build Objective-C module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, cocoapods

I am having this workspace (partially generated by this podfile)

[image]

```
# Podfile
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'Wynton.xcworkspace'

def regular_pods
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'Starscream', '~> 3.0'
end

def testing_pods
  pod 'Nimble', '~> 8.0'
  pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'RxTest', '~> 5.0'
end

# WYNTON
target 'Wynton' do
  project 'Wynton.xcodeproj'
  inherit! :search_paths
  regular_pods
  pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.0'

  # UNIT TESTS
  target 'WyntonTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    regular_pods
    testing_pods
  end

end

# WYNTON HOST
target 'WyntonHost' do
  project 'WyntonHost/WyntonHost.xcodeproj'
  inherit! :search_paths
  regular_pods
  pod 'RealtimeWatchdog', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Watchdog', '~> 5.1'
end
```

There are 4 projects in the workspace.

```
1. Pods (the cocoapods)
2. Mirga (my static c++ library) no dependencies
3. Wynton (my mixed framework, swift and objc) is depending on Mirga. Offers the root view controller and other ui stuff. A collection of things i want to share
4. Host (the application that uses Wynton and some Pods, only has an AppDelegate.swift file)
```

Now when i try to archive, test or build the `Wynton` framework, everthing looks fine.

But when i try to run the `WyntonHost`, the compiler fails with this error.

```
<module-includes>:3:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:3:
#import "../Mirga/AudioInputMapper.h"
        ^
/Users/mlostek/Projects/project/wynton/Wynton/WyntonPrivate/../Mirga/AudioInputMapper.h:4:9: error: 'MirgaFactory.h' file not found
#import "MirgaFactory.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'WyntonPrivate'
```

The strange thing is its happening from here

```
import UIKit
import Watchdog
import Wynton //=> this is where the compile error is coming from

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window:    UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
        // no storyboard, we create it manually
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = AppViewController() // AppViewController is from Wynton Framework
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Inside `Wynton` i am having an internal module called `WyntonPrivate`. It contains stuff like this

```
module WyntonPrivate {
    header "../Mirga/AudioInputMapper.h"
    header "../Mirga/Factory/MirgaFactory.h"
    header "../Mirga/Wrapper/MirgaWrapper.h"
    header "../Mirga/Wrapper/PerformanceInterfaceWrapper.h"
    export *
}
```

This file is set as "private module map file" in the build settings.

**What is the issue here?**